# How to check checkbox in repeater with protractor

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor, end-to-end

I am having difficulty checking a checkbox in an AngularJs repeater with protractor.

The model looks like this:

```
environments: [
                {
                    name: 'Proof of Concept',
                    checked: false
                },
                {
                    name: 'Non-Production',
                    checked: false
                },
                {
                    name: 'Production',
                    checked: false
                }
            ]
```

The view like this:

```
<div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="environment in vm.assessment.environments">
  <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.assessment.environments[$index].checked" ng-click="vm.checkboxChanged()" ng-required="!vm.someChecked">{{environment.name}}</label>


</div>
```

Am getting the repeater in protractor like so:

```
this.environments = element.all(by.repeater('environment in vm.assessment.environments'));
```

And trying to check the checkbox like this but when i run the test it does not seem to check it:

```
this.environments.get(0).click();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And trying to check the checkbox like this but when i run the test it does not seem to check it:

That is because you are clicking the repeater item - the `div` element, but need to click the `input` child element instead, I suspect.

You can *chain* the `.all()` and `.element()` calls in a single expression:

```
this.environments.first().element(by.css("input[ng-model$=checked]")).click();
```

Comment: alecxe is correct, as usual :)
Also try this syntax, i prefer to use $ :
    this.environments.first().$("input[ng-model*='environments']").click();

Answer (score 1):

Try using the below code to click the checkboxes.

```
var repeaterElement = element.all(by.repeater('environment in vm.assessment.environments'))

repeaterElement.then(function (ElementArray) {
  for(i = 0; i < ElementArray.length; i++) {
    ElementArray[i].all(by.tagName('input')).get(0).click();
    browser.sleep(1000);
  }
})
```