# Error clicking checkbox in protractor

Tags: typescript, protractor

I am trying to click one check box within ng-repeater in protractor for following html

[image]

The code I am using is;

```
element.all(by.repeater('user in siteUsers | filter: { SiteId: site.SiteId }'))
            .then(function (ElementArray) {
                ElementArray[0].all(by.tagName('input')).get(0).click();
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
```

But I get following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'all' of undefined
    at C:\AGLRepository\Agl.Digital.SolarCommand.WebApi\e2eTests\src\components\settings\addRemoveUsers\addRemoveUsers.page.ts:87:32
    at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (C:\Users\MyDevMachine\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1379:14)
    at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\MyDevMachine\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2913:14)
    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\MyDevMachine\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2896:21)
```

Further I referred following link solutions as well. No luck though.

Thanks in advance.

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37558845/how-to-check-checkbox-in-repeater-with-protractor)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.all()` incorrectly. Checkout the below extract from the official documentation

> element.all(locator).all(locator) View code
>   ElementArrayFinder.prototype.all
>
> Calls to ElementArrayFinder may be chained to find an array of
>   elements using the current elements in this ElementArrayFinder as the
>   starting point. This function returns a new ElementArrayFinder which
>   would contain the children elements found (and could also be empty).

You are using this - `ElementArray[0].all(by.tagName('input')).get(0).click()`
Correct Usage - `ElementArray.all(by.tagName('input')).get(0).click()`

And additional information on the best practices. You need not resolve the promise of `element.all()`. You can do something like below

`element.all(by.repeater('blah in blahs')).all(by.tagName('input')).get(0).click()`

Comment: `ElementArray[0].all(by.tagName('input')).get(0).click()` should work fine. The problem here is no element is retured for locator `by.repeater('user in siteUsers | filter: { SiteId: site.SiteId }')`.So ElementArray will be empty and  ElementArray[0] will be undefined. May be adding some wait will resolve the issue.

Comment: @AdityaReddy I tried this code `element.all(by.repeater('user in siteUsers | filter: { SiteId: site.SiteId }')).all(by.tagName('input')).get(0).click(); ` Then I got the error which is `Failed: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 0, but there are only 0 elements that match locator By(css selector, input) ` On the UI I can see the check box but not the clicking event. Wgat could be the reason?

Comment: @Sudharsan Selvaraj, I applied `browser.wait(() => 1000); ` before the code. Didn't help though.

Comment: @SudharsanSelvaraj .. you are right .. all() can be applied on element also.
@ OP yes, The error you are seeing is because no elements are returned based on the repeater value

Comment: If I can see the check box in the UI what could be the possible case where don't see any elements returned on the repeater?

Comment: @Sudharsan Selvaraj I did realized that I have added the browser wait at the wrong place. It worked well after placing it in the correct location which is just before the checkbox click. BTW is there a way we can get rid of `browser.sleep(500); ` as it's a kind of a hack for me. Even `waitForAngular() ` doesn't work along without browser.sleep();